# secure WebSocket on gateway spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, security, spring-security, spring-cloud, gateway

everyone! Do any of you have knowledge about securing a WebSocket connection on a gateway? I'm currently implementing JWT for authentication, and I would prefer not to pass the token as query parameters

Comment: Did you try Spring Security WebSocket authentication? https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/integrations/websocket.html